# Limit executing pipeline by object unit

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I'm using PowerShell script to get a list of all users with full mailbox access and need to limit it by only one object unit. However, my own modification did not bring the correct results and script is still running on all users:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission |
 where {$_.OrganizationalUnit -eq “Contoso.com/Users/test/" -and $_.user.tostring() -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false} |
 Select Identity,User,@{Name='Access Rights';Expression={[string]::join(', ', $_.AccessRights)}} |
 Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation \\sharename\mailboxpermissions.csv
```

Comment: what does "one object unit" mean?

Comment: Just a regular object unit in Active directory. Meant specific object unit not all mailboxes on Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another `select` where you only select one object:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | 
    Get-MailboxPermission | 
    where {$_.OrganizationalUnit -eq “Contoso.com/Users/test/" -and $_.user.tostring() -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false} | 
    Select -first 1 |
    Select Identity,User,@{Name='Access Rights';Expression={[string]::join(', ', $_.AccessRights)}} | 
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation \\sharename\mailboxpermissions.csv
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your answer. Just tried your code but still see that script is running on all mailboxes.

Comment: did you checked the CSV?

Comment: csv is empty and script after long time breaks up with error and this is not surprising as powershell process takes about 5Gb of memory!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, problem was solved by using -organizationalUnit filter. So the code should be the following:

```
  Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -organizationalUnit "ou=Users,ou=City,ou=county,dc=domain,dc=com" | Get-MailboxPermission | where {$_.user.tostring() -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false} | Select Identity,User,@{Name='Access Rights';Expression={[string]::join(', ', $_.AccessRights)}} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation \\sharename\mailboxpermissions.csv
```